# Word for "to support, to giveback, to be the supplier in some situation"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for "to support, giveback, to be the supplier in some situation"? Three examples:

- "To give back to his community, Chris helps clear the roads around
  his neighborhood of any loose trash."
- "Sarah felt that when using torrents, she should not only leach, but seed for others.
- "Sean bears a sense of guilt for using StackExchange for questions, but never providing answers; perhaps that will change one day."

What word best encapsulates that desire to "give back" to an entity, be that to people or a goal such as an open-source project?

Comment: The desire to do so.

Comment: I was unaware of this term, "duty-bound". I believe one could view this as a hyponym to "Obligation".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sense of (moral) *[obligation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obligation)* (ODOL)

> **1.2** A debt of gratitude for a service or favour.
>    ‘I recognize research and scholarship as a public trust and accept professional service as a societal obligation.’

Also,

> "She felt under a sort of moral obligation not to be indifferent."

[*Moral obligation*](https://wordnetonline.com/en/moral_obligation.n.01) (Wordnet)

> an obligation arising out of considerations of right and wrong
>   ("H)e did it out of a feeling of moral obligation(.)"

Comment: "Obligation" makes sense; my mind somewhat associated "obligation" with a negative connotation. Not sure why that was.

Thank you

Comment: That's because it also has a meaning that implies having to do something against one's own will. However, that's just one of the several meanings of the word *obligation*.